# Check if words have the same letters - Misses one test

Tags: javascript

I am doing an exercise which consists on checking if two words have the same letters. So far, my code has passed all tests but one. I am trying to understand why.

This is what i have:

```
function mutation(arr) {

 var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
 var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();

 for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
   var tmp = first.indexOf(second[i]);
   if(tmp < 0){
     return false;
   }else {
     return true;
   }
  }

 }
```

The only exception to pass are the words "hello" and "hey".
Could someone explain what am i missing?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't that just checking if the first letter is the same. Since you are returning after the first iteration.

Comment: So you want to check if those two words are anagrams ?

Comment: You have a loop over `first.length` but inside you take `second[i]`. Should be `var tmp = second.indexOf(first[i]);` and move `return false` to the end of your function

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is an anagram. It just needs to check if the same letters exist in both, regardless of order. For example, the words "hey" and "hello" should return false because the word hello doesn't have an "y". I have tried Kirils' solution but it didn't work :/

Comment: What is the definition of "two words have the same letters"?

Comment: msfoster, have an example: the words "care" and "race". They have have same letters. "Tour" and "our" do not, since "our" does not have the "t"

Comment: Does "mom" and "momo" have the same letters?

Answer (score 0):

the test checks only one direction. If you have the words: 'hello' and 'hhhhh' then all the test will pass because all it will do its check for the 'h' inside the 'hello' for every loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is the problem. Instead of using return true/false, place a console.log with the i variable in there and you'll see that your loop runs only once. Once the return statement is reached, you exit out of the function right there.

One more issue you'll run into with your loop is you need to have "first" be the shorter word, otherwise, when the loop gets to the 4th letter of `hhhhhhhello`, it can't check the 4th letter of `hey` because it only has 3, so you'll get an error (this won't happen with every scenario like hello/hey, but you need to plan for that as well).

You can keep the `return false;` portion. But remove the else{ return true;} altogether and create a conditional for when you specifically reach the end of the loop. Below is an example of one way to do this.

```js
function mutation(arr) {
  

  var first = arr[0].toLowerCase();
  var second = arr[1].toLowerCase();

  for (var i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    var tmp = first.indexOf(second[i]);
    if (tmp < 0) {
      $("#letters").append(second[i] + " is NOT in " + first + "<br>");
      return false;
    } else {
      $("#letters").append(second[i] + " is in " + first + "<br>");
    }
  }

}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="letters"></div>
```